# UIBezierPath Core Animation reverse both strokeStart and strokeEnd

Tags: swift, animation, uibezierpath, cabasicanimation, caanimation

I'm trying to create an indefinite loader where a bar moves from left to right. It's kind of like the spinner you see in Google Apps, but then a bar. This blog is a great post to show how a spinner like that can be created using UIBezierPaths and CABasicAnimation:

http://blog.matthewcheok.com/design-teardown-spinning-indicator/

But in my case, I want to do the same with a bar. So there's a line that goes from left to right, and like in the spinner, I also animate the strokeStart with a small delay such that it seems to follow the line and catch up with it at the end.
And when it reaches the end, I want it to go back from right to left, etcetera.
All of this using easeIn and easeOut. And I don't want the line to be invisible when it reaches the end, a small part should always remain visible.

To make my explanation much more clear, this is what I'm going for:

[image]

I know it seems like I already have want I want, but I created this gif by using ugly delay-code that don't work correctly half of the time.

So, to continue, the auto-reverse property of the CABasicAnimation can't be used because I animate both strokeEnd and strokeStart, so I had two ideas:

1. Use only one layer and update the bezierPath as soon as the line reaches the left or right end.
2. Use two animated layers and simply replace the one with the other as soon as the line reaches the left or right end.

Now, I got quite far, but the tricky part is when I have to switch the layers around. I always see a flicker, whatever I try. I know I have to use the presentation layer and set the right values before or after adding the animated group.

I use the CATransaction.setCompletionBlock to know when either the left or right part has been reached, and then I turn the other way.

Here are some parts of code I've written:

UIBezierPaths:

```
    let start:CGPoint = .init(x: 0, y: 0)
    let end:CGPoint = .init(x: frame.width, y: 0)
        
    let pathLeft = UIBezierPath()
    pathLeft.move(to: start)
    pathLeft.addLine(to: end)
    self.barLayerLeft.path = pathLeft.cgPath
       
    let pathRight = UIBezierPath()
    pathRight.move(to: end)
    pathRight.addLine(to: start)
    self.barLayerRight.path = pathRight.cgPath
```

Setup strokeStart and strokeEnd animations and a group

```
    let strokeStartAnimation: CAAnimation = {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeStart")
        animation.fromValue = 0
        animation.toValue = 0.99
        animation.beginTime = 0.3
        animation.duration = 1
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
        return animation
    }()
    
    let strokeEndAnimation: CAAnimation = {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation.fromValue = 0
        animation.toValue = 1
        animation.beginTime = 0
        animation.duration = 1.3
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
        return animation
    }()
```

Group & layers

```
    let groupedAnimation:CAAnimationGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
    groupedAnimation.duration = 1.4
    groupedAnimation.animations = [self.strokeStartAnimation, self.strokeEndAnimation]
        
    self.barLayerLeft.lineWidth = 4
    self.barLayerLeft.lineCap = .round
    self.barLayerLeft.strokeColor = AppStyler.mainColor.cgColor
    self.layer.addSublayer(self.barLayerLeft)
      
    self.barLayerRight.lineWidth = 4
    self.barLayerRight.lineCap = .round
    self.barLayerRight.strokeColor = AppStyler.mainColor.cgColor
    self.layer.addSublayer(self.barLayerRight)
```

Animate left (incl. setting the final positions so the animated line will stay exactly where it was when the animation finished, and removing the right-to-left bar)

```
    self.barLayerLeft.strokeEnd = 1
    self.barLayerLeft.strokeStart = 0.01
    self.barLayerRight.strokeEnd = 1
    self.barLayerRight.strokeStart = 0
    
    self.barLayerLeft.add(self.groupedAnimation, forKey: "groupLeft")
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock{ [weak self] in
        self.animateRight()        
    }
```

Animate right (and incl. positions like above)

```
    self.barLayerRight.strokeEnd = 1
    self.barLayerRight.strokeStart = 0.01        
    self.barLayerLeft.strokeEnd = 1
    self.barLayerLeft.strokeStart = 0
        
    self.barLayerRight.add(self.groupedAnimation, forKey: "groupRight")
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock{ [weak self] in
        self.animateLeft()        
    }
```

I've already tried using 'CATransaction.setDisableActions' to switch the layers without seeing a flicker like this:

```
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
    self.barLayerLeft.strokeEnd = 0.01
    self.barLayerLeft.strokeStart = 0
    self.barLayerRight.strokeEnd = 1
    self.barLayerRight.strokeStart = 0
    CATransaction.commit()
```

But I can't get it to work...

So, my main question is. Can my ideas above actually work without flickering? Or do I need to use something else entirely...? Is there a way easier/better way to achieve what I want?

Btw, if anything is unclear or if I need to post more code, let me know!

Comment: How about a drawing of what you want? I can't understand what the goal is.

Comment: @matt yeah, I was afraid my explanation wouldn’t be enough . I’ll post a link to a video on monday

Comment: I'd approach this by having a single layer of a fixed width which represents your line, and have that move left and right within a separate layer which is clipping to bounds. So when it's at the far left extent, you only see the rightmost edge, and vice versa.

Comment: @matt I just added a gif, I hope this will make it more clear?

Comment: Well, although jrturton's implementation does not get exactly what you want, I agree completely with the idea of simply moving a bar with rounded ends back and forth within a mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this using masking and a single moving layer:

```swift
let container = CALayer()
container.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 200, height: 10)
container.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
container.borderWidth = 1
container.cornerRadius = 5
container.masksToBounds = true
view.layer.addSublayer(container)
let bar = CALayer()
bar.frame = container.bounds
bar.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
bar.position = CGPoint(x: -195, y: 5)
bar.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
container.addSublayer(bar)
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position.x")
animation.fromValue = bar.position.x
animation.toValue = 195
animation.autoreverses = true
animation.repeatCount = .infinity
animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
animation.duration = 2
bar.add(animation, forKey: nil)
```

Looks like this, but less terrible because it's not a GIF:

[image]

This would be much simpler to pause at the end of your work, as it's a single animation.

For a bar that doesn't fill the whole area, change the frame of the bar:

```swift
bar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 75, height: 10)
```

And the start position:

```swift
bar.position = CGPoint(x: -70, y: 5)
```

Which gives you:

[image]

You can round the edges of the moving bar like so:

```swift
bar.cornerRadius = 5
```

Comment: Thanks! But if you look at the gif I added in my question, you'll see what I'm going for. The tail should follow the head quite fast instead of waiting until the head reached the end.

Comment: You can do that by making the bar frame's width less than the container width, and adjusting the start and end points.

Comment: You are not capturing the rounding of the visible end of the bar.

Comment: Don't make me upload _another_ gif, please

Comment: @jrturton, thanks for all the things you’ve been doing, I do appreciate it. But, and please tell me if I’m wrong, the tail is still not catching up, right? It seems like a bar of a specific length, and the longer the distance, the better you’ll see that.

Comment: Oh I see, I originally thought the bar shortened as it reached the end, but looking more closely at your gif it is shortening as it goes. You could experiment with animating the transform.scale.x of the bar or possibly wrap the container in another masking container and move that in a similar way? If I get some more time today I will take another look, I do enjoy these sorts of things

Comment: Haha all right, I get what you mean, I also enjoy toying around with animations like that. Btw, it might not be necessary, though. I’ve used your code and showed it around and it actually already looks really good! So there’s a good chance I’ll use this as it is, so I’ve also accepted your answer as the solution. Thanks a lot! :)